# Can a wine app access files outside of the wine drive_c environment?

Tags: filesystem, wine

I am running [Avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) witih [avidemux+avsproxy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10134/how-to-use-wine-and-avisynth-and-avs2yuv-with-mplayer-mencoder-or-any-player/10172#10172) in wine, but the files which AviSynth needs to access via its .avs scripts must be in Windows format (eg. "C:\my\avisynth.avs").
Most of the files I want to access are not in wine's `drive_c`...
Is there some way to address my home directory, and other  drives/directories?  .. eg. as `drive_d`..`drive_n` perhaps?

Comment: is it not possible to run avisynth natively?

Comment: @Ronald... AviSynth is definitely Windows only.. I've read (somewhere) that there was an attempt several years ago to port it to 'nix.. (as a multi-platorm Avisnth 3.0, I believe), but the developer couldn't get around some of the Windows specific issues that were deeply embedded in his original design. It's a pity, becaue it is such a powerful audio/video scripted language....(you can do "almost" anything with it... It is a scriptable frame server, so there are no gi-normous temp files floatting around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wine manages the drive letters through the ~/.wine/dosdevices directory.  On my system with the default configuration, I have:

```
$ ls ~/.wine/dosdevices/ -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james 10 2010-07-21 22:51 c: -> ../drive_c
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james  1 2010-07-21 22:51 z: -> /
```

So, the ~/.wine/drive_c folder is mapped to c:, and the root folder is mapped to z: (which means wine programs can access my home directory as z:\home\james).

If I wanted to expose my home directory as h: directly, I could do it as follows:

```
$ ln -s $HOME ~/.wine/dosdevices/h:
```

Comment: Thanks mate! brilliant! ... For a fully qualified filename, all that is needed is: `fnameWin="Z:$fnameNix"` does the trick... '/' and '\' are both accepted.

Comment: @fred: You can use the GUI for that too... Menu > Wine > Configure Wine > Drives tab. Also, as security measure, I suggest you create a drive D: mapping to your $HOME folder, and **delete** the Z: association. You *don't* want windows apps having access to your entire tree.